# how to Rotate a 3gp video without re-encoding

Tags: encoding

I created a video in my cellphone holding the phone in portrait mode. The video is 720p and it looks perfectly fine in cell phone. I copied it on computer and when viewing it, the video looks 90 degrees anti-clockwise rotated. It is confusing for me that why it happened. How can I rotate the copied video back to 90-degrees without re-enconding the video.

Comment: It has been answered to death already. Not possible, unless container supports it or you are using MJPEG codec, which you are not.

Comment: @Volodya ok, deleted my answer, but might be better suggest a duplicate instead of downvoting it.

Comment: @poor I've clicked downvote on your answer by some weird accident. Tried to undo, but it didn't let me.

Comment: @Volodya this is the only one I've found here: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15013/avconv-rotating-mpeg4-video-loses-quality/15021#15021 and I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @poor Ok, i now feel dumb. There were several questions, some of which have provided a very in depth explanations on how to rotate mjpeg via bash scripts and imagic. It really feels like somebody has gone on a cleaning spree and has removed too much. Alternatively i've dreamt all those questions. I'm trying to find them now on other SE.

Comment: @Volodya I think only equal questions are **real duplicates** (avconv rotation is not equal to _How to rotate my 3gp video_), but we could post a meta, if you are interested and also suggest a duplicate if you find one. I've undelete my answer, just to have an answer for this question, see the statistics: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4/audio-video-production.

Comment: Apparently my answer doesn't solve your issue. Please let us know, what else you need or edit your question.

Comment: @poor Yet another drive-by-question.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Haha - a **drive-by-question** ;) Made my day. Upvoted your answer to prevent that this question comes over and over again... Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

## Rotate without re-encoding

You can add rotation metadata:

```
ffmpeg -i input.3gp -c copy -metadata:s:v rotate=90 output.3gp
```

- `-c copy` will enable [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode, so it will just re-mux instead of re-encode.
- Player and device support for the `rotate` metadata may vary, so your player or device may not actually rotate the video. If that is the case you may have to manually rotate within the player, or re-encode.

## Rotate with re-encoding

When re-encoding `ffmpeg` will automatically rotate the video. The rotate metadata/sidedata will not be copied from the input (which is a good thing).

```
ffmpeg -i input output
```

If it doesn't work for you then your build is too old. Refer to the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page.

Comment: Any idea why rotating 90 deg does 180, and rotating 360 does 90? haha